# PHP & SimpleXML H elp with parsing

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I got the following test.xml

```
<Segment xmlnssi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlnssd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Elements>
<Text>
<Value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Value>
</Text>
</Elements>
<CultureName>XXXXXX</CultureName>
</Segment>
```

I spend hours reading tutorials for SimpleXML and RegEx, but I didnt get a working parser. The test.xml File needs to be parsed for the value in the Value Tags. So in the end I want to get an Array or a list with all the words between the Value Tags. The .xml file is consisting of several hundred of those entires you can see above. Only the XXXXXXX differs. So its like:

```
<Segment xmlnssi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlnssd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Elements>
<Text>
<Value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Value>
</Text>
</Elements>
<CultureName>XXXXXX</CultureName>
</Segment>
<Segment xmlnssi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlnssd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Elements>
<Text>
<Value>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</Value>
</Text>
</Elements>
<CultureName>YYYYYYYY</CultureName>
</Segment>
....
....
....
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me getting done a PHP SimpleXML parser for this.

Comment: I tried copy pasting many examples and then changing the variables according to my files. Most of the time though I got strange errors telling me that it's not an object or something. Another time I got an output but it was only like this Array Array Array Array Array Array like hundreds of times

Comment: If you've already tried something, it's better to post it and that way you can get help on specific problems/errors, instead of just asking for "help getting something done" out of nothing...

Comment: `I got strange errors telling me that it's not an object or something`. Lesson #1: pay great attention to error messages! Even if you hate them, they're your biggest friend when something doesn't work

Comment: Posting code that got close is more useful than posting no code; I can't quite guess which example you copy and pasted, however.

Comment: I would have done that, if I would have something that works to like 50% already. What I had though was total crap and most of the time didn't work at all. I tried at least 20 different codes in the last hours, but I didnt bother to save them, as they were faulty.  I hoped that someone would be able to tell me how to write a parser for this thing as it does seem to be against some standard with its tags or something... Otherwise those example codes should have worked I guess -.-

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using XPath if this is a well-formed XML document. That might be easier to extract:

```
$results = $simplexmlelement->xpath('/Segment/Elements/Text/Value');
```

Comment: What exactly would you consider well-formed? I'd say my xml file is the complete opposite. It doesnt look well formed to me at least and has like 7k+ lines with 400+ characters each line.

Comment: sorry, "well structured" would be more correct....no missing tags, weird or random & in there, etc. If SimpleXML can load it, it sounds like it's valid.

Comment: Tried your code and got following errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: simplexmlelement in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser.php on line 2

Comment: Er sorry...I assume you'd know to substitute your variable from the SimpleXML import call there. Not literally `$simplexmlelement`